# Syntax for creating database and schemas with knex and bookshelf?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have some working code that uses knex and bookshelf to set up a Sqlite3 database and tables.  It doesn't look like what I'm seeing on the Bookshelf website, though.  [This blog post](http://blog.reidransom.com/2014/04/06/bookshelf.js-example.html) seems to indicate that creating things is knex's job, but I don't see `Bookshelf.conn` stuff on the Bookshelf website either. Can I use something like this code to create a Postgres database and tables?

This is the code that worked (package.json has "knex": "~0.5.7" and "bookshelf": "~0.6.4", currently they're both at 0.9):

```
var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf');
var path = require('path');

var db = Bookshelf.initialize({
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'your_database_user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database_name',
    charset: 'utf8',
    filename: path.join(__dirname, '../db/mydb.sqlite')
  }
});

db.knex.schema.hasTable('urls').then(function(exists) {
  if (!exists) {
    db.knex.schema.createTable('urls', function (link) {
      link.increments('id').primary();
      link.string('url', 255);
      link.string('base_url', 255);
      link.string('code', 100);
      link.string('title', 255);
      link.integer('visits');
      link.timestamps();
    }).then(function (table) {
      console.log('Created Table', table);
    });
  }

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: So, what seems to be the problem here? Have you tried it and it produced any errors?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with `Bookshelf` or `Knex` but have you tried this?

```
var db = Bookshelf.initialize({
  client: 'postgresql',
  connection: {
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'your_database_user',
    port     : '5432',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test',
    charset  : 'UTF8_GENERAL_CI'
  }
});
```

Comment: I went googling to look into your 'port' property, and found this issue on knex's github: https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/299  There the author says that Bookshelf.initialize uses "the already configured Knex instance internally in Bookshelf".  Now I have a much better sense of what's going on.  Thanks for having a go at this problem!

Comment: if the question helped you, please upvote and mark it right so others can have a clue when they searched for your problem. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Once I try to run the above code with the 0.9 versions of knex and bookshelf, I get the response "Bookshelf.initialize is deprecated, pass knex directly: require('bookshelf')(knex)".  As mentioned in a comment, Bookshelf.initialize used "the already configured Knex instance internally in Bookshelf" but apparently sometime between March 2014 and now that fell by the wayside.

Comment: Just take the hash you are passing to initialize and pass it to knex then pass that knex instance to bookshelf. It's documented on the bookshelf.js project page as the simple example

Answer (score 0):

```
var  knex = require('knex')(
{
  client: 'postgresql',
  connection: {
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'your_database_user',
    port     : '5432',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test',
    charset  : 'UTF8_GENERAL_CI'
  }
});
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
```